# BizTalk polling from SQL - Commit/Rollback transaction

Tags: sql, biztalk

I have a receive location which is doing polling on a stored procedure with WCF-SQL adapter.

The receive location is using a custom pipeline.

That stored procedure is doing "UPDATE" action on some rows.

I need the BizTalk to perform ROLLBACK on the transaction in case the pipeline fails in a later stage.

How should I do it ?

Answer (score 2):

By default, the WCF-SQL adapter will call your stored proc under a [distributed DTC transaction](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3470.typed-polling-with-wcf-sql-adapter-best-practices-and-troubleshooting-tips.aspx)

This setting (`UseAmbientTransaction`) is on the Receive Location properties, Binding tab, Transaction.

(Untested!) This should mean that if the proc or pipeline fails, the connection will be rolled back automatically.

This should similarly enforce 2 phase commit / ACID on the adapter, when used under a scope of an atomic scope in an orchestration as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried to set "UseAmbientTransaction" = True, but the BizTalk engine didn't roll back the transaction (I mean, the rows got updated) when the pipeline failed.

Comment: @user1003363 It seems I've only been using standard XmlReceive on WCF-SQL. Thiago has some more on this here : http://connectedthoughts.wordpress.com/2010/03/24/hooking-into-biztalks-underlying-transaction-in-your-custom-receive-pipeline-component/. I'm guessing because each poll pulls a batch that BTS commits because a) the PROC succeeds and b) the batch is successfully committed into the messagebox.

Comment: so there is no way doing rollback with a custom pipeline ?